# Cardinality of connected manifolds

Tags: manifolds

Consider the assertion:

Every connected, but not necessarily paracompact, n-manifold is of cardinality 
$2^{\aleph_0}$ (at least assuming the axiom of choice).

For n=1 this may be proved via enumeration of the short list of examples. The essential point is that while there is a Long Line, there is no Extra Long Line.

What is the situation for n>1?

Comment: Your assertion is about the size of manifolds, but your comment is about the number of such manifolds. What is your exact question?

Comment: As posed, about cardinality. One could pose the weaker question, of whether there is any upper bound on cardinality. That in turn is  equivalent to the motivating question, of whether there are  only 'set-many' homeomorphism types of connected manifolds. Assuming paracompactness, there is a trivial 'yes' answer. 

Comment: You should add that you want Haudsdorff, since without this there is a classical counterexample.

Comment: True enough. Meanhwile, which of the above statements would be violated?

Comment: @Adam: A non-Hausdorff manifold of arbitrary cardinal larger than the continuum  can be constructed by considering $\mathbb R$ with many, many origins, generalizing the usual construction of the line with two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A connected Hausdorff manifold with more than one point has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Here's a proof sketch.

For each point $x$ of the manifold, let $U_x$ be an open Euclidean neighbourhood of $x$. Define a transfinite sequence of subsets $V_\alpha$ of the manifold as follows. Choose some point $y$ of the manifold, and put $V_0=U_y$. For each ordinal $\alpha$, let $V_{\alpha+1}$ be the union of $U_x$ over all $x$ such that $x$ is a limit of a sequence in $V_\alpha$. Take unions at limit ordinals.

Each $V_\alpha$ is open, and $V_{\omega_1}$ is clearly sequentially closed, and therefore closed (as manifolds are first countable), and is therefore the whole space (by connectedness). As we are assuming that the manifold is Hausdorff, sequential limits are unique, so it follows easily by transfinite induction that $V_{\omega_1}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: That's a really nice argument. 

Comment: Indeed! It is the natural thing to do, yet it is not quite obvious *how* to carry it out. 

Answer (score 6):

Stephen's argument can also be phrased in the language of model theory. Given a connected manifold $X$, consider an elementary submodel of a large fragment of set theory $\mathfrak{M}$ that (1) contains all the reals,
(2) is closed under countable subsets, (3) contains $X$ as an element
and (4) is of size $2^{\aleph_0}$.
It suffices to show that $X\subseteq \mathfrak{M}$. But $X\cap \mathfrak{M}$ is open since each point of $X$ has a neighbourhood of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ and, by elementarity there is a bijection from the reals to this neighbourhood and, since the $\mathfrak M$ contains the reals it must also contain the image of this bijection, namely the neighbourhood. But $X\cap \mathfrak{M}$ is also closed since $\mathfrak M$ contains all sequences from $X\cap \mathfrak{M}$ and hence their unique (by Hausdorffness) limits. By connectedness $X\cap \mathfrak{M} = X$.

Comment: It is obvious that such an $\mathfrak M$ exists?

Comment: Yes, this follows from the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem.

Comment: @Juris: Nice solution! Technically speaking, Lowenheim-Skolem cannot be invoked unless we are working in Kelley-Morse theory of classes (where there is a truth-definition for $(V,\in))$; but what "saves the day" and makes your proof implementable in $ZF$, is the $ZF$-*Reflection Theorem*.

Comment: @Ali: The phrase "elementary submodel of a large fragment of set theory" does sweep a bit under the rug. I had in mind simply, for any manifold taking a submodel of $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is larger than he cardinality of the manifold. Of course, this also the strategy for proving reflection.

Comment: @Juris: right, I see your point.  By the way, is there a similar proof [using elementary submodels] of Arhangel'ski's theorem about the maximum cardinality of first countable Lindelof Haussdorf spaces?